# Custom Login form in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm creating a system in Django with admins(not superuser) and employees working under them. I've created admins registration and login using Django's built-in models. Now I have created custom model for employee's profile. The admin can only register the employee using his dashboard. This part has been done. Now I want to know that how to authenticate the employee's credentials so that the he/she can login to his/her own dashboard?
Note that the admin and superuser are different in this case. Admin cannot access superuser's panel.

The models are:

```
#ADMIN PROFILE 
class AdminProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/admin/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username

#EMPLOYEE PROFILE
class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    admin_name = models.ForeignKey(AdminProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/employee/', blank=True) 


    def __str__(self):
         return self.email
```

I want to have login validation for `EmployeeProfile` model.

I have already tried custom authentication using backends but it failed.

I'm new to Django and this is the part of my first project in Django.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** I solved this question by extending User model in the Employee profile as well.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this inside of the Django admin panel or you will create a custom admin panel?

Comment: I want to create a custom admin panel. Actually the custom admin panel has been already created. The admin can add the employee through his panel. Now I want to login the employee to employee's panel by that details entered.

Comment: I think the best way to do this, Is to have your EmployeeProfile extend Django's User model. The same way you did for AdminProfile.

Comment: I did this too but by doing this, the employee's email and password will get added into User table along with admin's credentials in superuser's panel. But I want to have a separate table for Employee.

Comment: Writing a custom authentication scheme is not a good idea. It's too much of a hassle. Maybe you should try extending Django's 'AbstractUser' or Django's 'AbstractBaseUser'.

Comment: Any link for this?

Comment: I found [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) to be very useful. Let me know if it helps solve your specific use case.

Comment: I'm getting this error: AdminDashboard.EmployeeProfile.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'EmployeeProfile.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'. I think the EmployeeProfile is clashing with AdminProfile.